# Transposing Instruments in Logic Pro

Tags: logic-pro, scoring

When composing in Logic Pro, how can I work with transposing instruments (for example a Clarinet in B♭) in the Score window?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to score as usual and set the transposition offset in the track parameters, or if you want to be more specific, in the region parameters. These are both edited in the inspector area. See [this page](http://goo.gl/kgJPI) from the Logic Pro 9 manual.